# Another Bash permission denied post

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I've spent the past hour trying to find a way around this before asking but to no avail so I'm asking.
I am trying to make a simple script that will take the name for a file and then generate a generic blank html template for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
blank=/home/sithyrys/Documents/scripts/blank.html
echo "Enter file name with no extensions:"
read fileName
fileName+=.html
echo $fileName
touch $fileName
$blank >> $fileName
```

When I comment out the path the code runs with no error message but then it's not pulling the template and it makes a blank page. The error message in question is:

```
./basicHTMLTemplate.sh: line 9: /home/sithyrys/Documents/scripts/blank.html: Permission denied
```

Edit: shebang line copied wrong that was correct already

Comment: First, I count only 8 lines. Second, who is running this script? Is it the sithyrys user?

Comment: ... and a blank.html not blank.txt

Comment: `cat "$blank" >> "$fileName"` (aka `cp "$blank" "$fileName"`).  As it is you're trying to execute the html file, which would probably not work well even if you had permissions.

Comment: As an aside, the shebang line is incorrectly transcribed; it needs to be `#!` not `!#` in order for it to work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>` does not copy a file; it appends the output of the command that precedes it to the file named following it. You need to use the `cat` command to actually "push" the contents of `blank.html` into the new file.

```
cat "$blank" >> "$fileName"
```

As written, your code accommodates the possibility that `$fileName` already exists and appends the contents of `$blank` without overwriting the existing file. In practice, it doesn't make much sense to append the template to the end of an existing file, so you probably just want to make a copy of the template.

```
#!/bin/bash
blank=/home/sithyrys/Documents/scripts/blank.html
echo "Enter file name with no extensions:"
read fileName
fileName+=.html
echo $fileName
cp "$blank" "$fileName"
```

(or, to guard against overwriting an existing file,

```
[[ -f "$fileName" ]] || cp "$blank" "$fileName"
```

)